# Image from JavaScript to PHP as Post Variable

Tags: javascript, php, post, filereader

I've seen lots of variations on this question, but none of them applies to this specific situation. I'm a bit confused because of all the data and object types.

Consider the following code in JavaScript:

```
function postRequest(url, params, success, error, keepactive = 1)
{
    let req = false;
    try
    {
        // most browsers
        req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e)
    {
        // IE
        try
        {
            req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e)
        {
            // try an older version
            try
            {
                req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    if (keepactive === 0)
    {
        ajaxcalls.push(req);
        console.log(ajaxcalls.length + ' calls active');
    } else if (keepactive === 2)
    {
        console.log('Filter call: ' + ajaxcalls.length + ' calls active');
        filtercall = req;
    } else if (keepactive === 3)
    {
        console.log('Jump call: ' + ajaxcalls.length + ' calls active');
        jumpcall = req;
    }
    if (!req) return false;
    if (typeof success != 'function') success = function ()
    {
    };
    if (typeof error != 'function') error = function ()
    {
    };
    req.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if (req.readyState === 4)
        {
            // Success! Remove req from active calls.
            if (keepactive === 0)
            {
                for (let i = ajaxcalls.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    if (ajaxcalls[i] === req)
                    {
                        ajaxcalls.splice(i, 1);
                        console.log(ajaxcalls.length + ' calls active');
                    }
                }
            }
            return req.status === 200 ?
                success(req.responseText) : error(req.status);
            // dus eigenlijk displayUpdateWorksheet(req.responseText)
            // dus eigenlijk displayUpdateWorksheetError(req.status)
        }
    }
    req.open("POST", url, true);
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    req.send(params);
    return req;
}

function uploadPicture(myindex, stringid)
{
    let file = document.getElementById("file").files[0];

    let contents = new FileReader(); // no arguments
    contents.readAsDataURL(file);

    contents.onload = function ()
    {
        // console.log(contents.result);
        let filename;
        let client;
        let field = myindex;
        let filecontainer = document.getElementById('file' + myindex);
        if (filecontainer != null)
        {
            filename = filecontainer.innerHTML.replace(/\+/g, '＋').replace(/&/g, '＆').replace(/#/g, '＃').replace(/%/g, '％');
        }
        let clientcontainer = document.getElementById('myclient');
        if (clientcontainer != null)
        {
            client = clientcontainer.innerHTML.replace(/\+/g, '＋').replace(/&/g, '＆').replace(/#/g, '＃').replace(/%/g, '％');
        }
        alert('Picture uploaded!');

        // let post_array = { client: client, stringid: stringid, filename: filename, field: field, contents: contents.result }

        postRequest(
            'ajaxcalls/ajaxUploadPicture.php', // url
            '&client=' + client +
            '&stringid=' + stringid +
            '&filename=' + filename +
            '&field=' + myindex +
            '&contents=' + contents.result +
            '&type=' + file.type,
            function (responseText)
            {
                return drawOutputUploadPicture(myindex, responseText);
            },  // success
            drawErrorUploadPicture   // error
        );
    }

    contents.onerror = function ()
    {
        console.log(contents.error);
    };

};
```

And the following PHP:

```
$data = $_POST['contents'];
$contents = preg_replace('#data:image/[^;]+;base64,#', '', $data);
$contents = base64_decode($contents);
...
file_put_contents($file_full, $contents);
```

($file_full is correct here: the file is saved at the right spot. I've just cut some irrelevant code there: nothing in $contents is changed after this.)

When I upload a 52K image, I lose about 1K and the resulting image cannot be opened. What's going on?

The main issue is that 1) I'm using POST with 2) multiple variables and 3) Vanilla JavaScript. I've seen no working examples of that.

When I open the original and copy as text, the beginning is the same:

```
Original: ���� JFIF  ` `  ���Exif
Copy: ���� JFIF  ` `  ���Exif
```

Then a series of NUL's in both files. Then the files start deviating:

Original:

```
   2021:07:22 16:21:52 2021:07:22 16:21:52   L o e k   v a n   K o o t e n   ��"http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/ <?xpacket begin='' id='W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d'?>
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/"><rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"><rdf:Description rdf:about="uuid:faf5bdd5-ba3d-11da-ad31-d33d75182f1b" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"/><rdf:Description rdf:about="uuid:faf5bdd5-ba3d-11da-ad31-d33d75182f1b" xmlns:xmp="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/"><xmp:CreateDate>2021-07-22T16:21:52.056</xmp:CreateDate></rdf:Description><rdf:Description rdf:about="uuid:faf5bdd5-ba3d-11da-ad31-d33d75182f1b" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"><dc:creator><rdf:Seq xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"><rdf:li>Loek van Kooten</rdf:li></rdf:Seq>
            </dc:creator></rdf:Description></rdf:RDF></x:xmpmeta>
```

Copy:

> 2021:07:22 16:21:52 2021:07:22 16:21:52   L o e k   v a n   K o o t
> e n
> �BȚ��ۜ˘YؙK���K�\�K���X��]�Y�[�I�����YI��SL\�ZR��Tޓ�ޚ��Y   �σB��\Y]H[�ΞH�YؙN��ΛY]Kȏ������[�Μ��H������˝�˛ܙ��NNNK��̌�\��\�[�^[��ȃ�&Fc�FW67&�F���&Fc�&�WC�'WV�C�fcV&FCR�&6B�F�C3�C36CsS�&c""����3�F3�&�GG���W&���&r�F2�V�V�V�G2���"���&Fc�FW67&�F���&Fc�&�WC�'WV�C�fcV&FCR�&6B�F�C3�C36CsS�&c""����3����&�GG����2�F�&R�6�������
> ���� ɕ�ѕ�є����Ĵ�ܴ��P�������ȸ�������
> ɕ�ѕ�є��ɑ���͍ɥ�ѥ����ɑ���͍ɥ�ѥ���ɑ�酉�����ե�际�Չ��Ե��͐��ő�����ĵ��͐����ɘň��ᵱ��鑌����輽��ɰ��ɜ�����������̼ĸļ�<dc:creator����\H[�Μ��H������˝�˛ܙ��NNNK��̌�\��\�[�^[��ȏ����O��Z��[����[�ܙ��O�ܙ���\O�B�BBO�ΘܙX]܏�ܙ��\�ܚ[ۏ�ܙ�����������WF4

Anyone recognizes what's going on here?

Comment: I don't see how this would save anything since `$file_put_contents($file_full, $contents);`  should be `file_put_contents($file_full, $contents);` (without the leading `$`)

Comment: That's a typo, but saving was never the issue. I just found out the cause. For some reason, in this case $_POST['contents'] contains spaces. If I replace these with + the image comes out nicely. I imagine that when a file is sent as a $_POST variable, it gets split with a space every so many characters.

Comment: There's also no need to use anything other than `XMLHttpRequest` since many years back. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#browser_compatibility

Comment: remove all xhr and use fetch instead. replace the filereader with FormData and do not read the blob content

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, in this case $_POST['contents'] contains spaces. If I replace these with + the image comes out nicely. I imagine that when a file is sent as a $_POST variable, it gets split with a space every so many characters.